# Code Igniter Form Validation Min Max Length count of unicode characters?

Tags: codeigniter, unicode, validation

Curious if anyone knows if codeigniter's form validation built in max_length[n] and min_length[n] functions count unicode characters as 1 character or the sum of all the characters used symbolize the unicode character?

I noticed when I var_dump the string it counts all the characters, just wondering if code igniter or php has a built in function to count unicode characters?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Codeigniter uses php's mb_strlen if it's available on your php installation which allows for an encoding parameter to be passed along, otherwise it defaults to php's basic strlength which doesn't allow you to pass the string encoding along. The trouble is that CI doesn't give you the ability to pass along the possible encoding for max_length[n]...

If you need it to compensate for the encoding, you might be better served rolling your own validation with just raw php.

Comment: hmmm.  Alright thats probably what I'll do.  Seems like thats probably something they should add in a future upgrade.

Answer (score 2):

You can make your own callback validation:

```
$this->form_validation->set_rules('rule', 'The rule', 'callback_checkUnicode');
```

And the check the unicode string>

```
public function checkUnicode($string)
{
    if (strlen($string) != strlen(utf8_decode($string)))
    {
            //is unicode: add your own counter condition here
        return true;
    }

    return false
}
```